# AS3 dress up game drag & drop not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a dress up game and ran into the following issue.

I know how to make things drag and drop, however whenever the movieclip is situated in a layer below another, it will not let me drop it / does not register the mouse release.

In this case for example - The very top layer is the doll's hair. Under this layer are articles of clothing, and under that is the doll base. Like so : https://gyazo.com/a0ea8eae2ee5505874f4207a888249bf

I can pick up a top from the inventory but cannot place it on the doll because my cursor is over the hair from the very top layer. In a way, it seems like the hair layer is acting as a barrier between the cursor click and the article of clothing. Is there any way around this?

Here is a link to the game as it is now - i'm sure you will see the issue quickly if you attempt to move things around.[GAME LINK](http://sta.sh/0n01sfvh8ze)

Here is the code for one of the clothing layers, if needed.

```
tshirt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag17);
tshirt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop17);
function drag17(event:MouseEvent):void
{
event.target.startDrag();
}
function drop17(event:MouseEvent):void
{
event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Sorry for the rather crude explanation, and thank you in advance!

Comment: When you drop an item, make that item mouseEnabled=false; From your example, if the hair is mouseEnabled=false, the release will work fine. Of course if you want to still be able to remove that hair you will have to have a way to turn mouseEnabled back to true. One way to do that would be to loop through all the elements when you pick one up, and change them all to false, and then when you drop the item change them all back to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### the problem

You are exactly right about the hair getting in the way.

### method 1

One way to fix that would be (assuming you dropped the hair there):

```
function drop17(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    event.target.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

In your hair example, the hair needs to have mouseEnabled set to false so that it won't be able to be your `target` by mistake on a mouse event. If the hair wasn't "dropped" there, set mouseEnabled to false for the hair wherever it makes sense to do so... maybe when it is first constructed or instantiated.

### method 2

An alternative method is to force the item that you picked up to come to the front of the z order. Like this:

```
function drag17(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    addChild(event.target); // this doesn't add another Sprite or movie clip, it just moves it to the top of the z order. Trust me. 
    event.target.startDrag();
}
```

With your dragging element now at the top, nothing will be "between" it and the mouse. This method probably looks cleaner since the thing you are dragging isn't getting lost behind other things. This will force you to deal with the eventual need to place the item in the correct z-order when you drop it, but that could easily be done by doing addChild to a clothesContainer or something like that. That would be another question though.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I have a really weak understanding of how as3 works so concerning your first method - how would i insert MouseEnabled = False into the hair layer? there is no drag / drag code for them. (sorry if this doesnt make sense!)

Comment: You'd have to do that for each and every thing that you don't want to get in the way of the mouse. It *could* be done in one fell swoop if you put them all in a container and then set that containers mouseEnabled value to false. But if not in one container, then do that with every element. So like `hair.mouseEnabled = false;` and then `eyelashes.mouseEnabled = false;`

Comment: @Alexia you may need to explain *exactly* what you mean by "layer". That can mean so many different things

Comment: Sorry about that! by Layer I mean the sections here: ( https://gyazo.com/40029ff9b481e7ab28355ac8cf9fdded ). I understand how mouseEnabled - False would work, the thing is i dont know as3 well enough to make it work without errors. I know simply copy pasting "hair.mouseEnabled = false;" alone doesnt work, but I dont know how to make it work.

Comment: Just to clarify; all the code for the hair is in here, on the Button layers

Comment: ( https://gyazo.com/5b53f1416d3928dacf81e17216fda64d ) - the code is all on the buttons ( https://gyazo.com/69de5e6edf9fc626dc713a71272a4647 ) - sorry once again for the bad explanations & messy information, I'm not very good at this!

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to refer to the hair in as3? I assume you are creating the hair in the IDE, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by refer so I'm going to assume I dont

Comment: tshirt.addEventListener is referring to something. A MovieClip of a t-shirt I assume. That's what I mean by refer. So do you know how to refer to the hair movie clip?  The hair just needs an instance name like "hairRed". Then you can do `hairRed.mouseEnabled =false`

Comment: do you mean something like the following :   hairRed.addEventListener();
{
 hairRed.mouseEnabled =false
}

Comment: No just `hairRed.mouseEnabled = false;` *do you* have a way to reference the hair? If so, what is it? What is its instance name?

Comment: No i do not currently - i could but again i dont know how to make it work without getting errors

Comment: How do you know it will give errors if you don't even have an instance name with which to *try* it?

Comment: Well I tried just now putting the one i sent 2 comments ago and it gave me an error

Comment: The addEventListener one?

Comment: yes - I mean I know theres things missing for it to work but I just dont have the understanding to know what it is

Comment: I'm trying to tell you. You need to add an instance name to the hair movie clip! `hairRed` has no meaning until you do that. Do you know how to add an instance name to a movie clip? You seem to since you reference `tshirt`.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry I finally get what you mean - yes i did give it an instance name. I just named it hairRed for the time being but again it didnt work

Comment: Ok so why did you do addEventListener? That's not what I suggested. I said very simply `hairRed.mouseEnabled = false;` when you try that what happens? An error message? What?

Comment: I misunderstood; I've removed that now and just put hairRed.mouseEnabled = false; - this gives me no errors but it also doesnt fix my original issue unfortunately :( Is this because all the hair movieclips & buttons concerning them are not in scene 1?

Comment: Probably not. If it were, it would lead to an error.

Comment: That's alright; thank you for your time and sorry for being so frustrating! I appreciate it

Comment: Don't mark my answer as accepted :) there are lots of helpful people on here that may take a look at it over the next couple of days. But if it's marked as answered, no one is very likely to pay it any attention. I'm pretty new to as3 too, so someone more experienced may be able to help better.